# How does the indexing in Argon2 work?

Tags: key-derivation, password-hashing, argon2

I am reading the original paper of Argon2 authors and I can understand the algorithm except the indexing part. Can anyone explain two things:

1. the indexing process and the mapping $J_{1}$, $J_{2}$ to reference block index.
2. How the $B_{i'j'}$ are fixed in Argon2d, Argon2i and Argon2id.

I tried to simplify things by taking a few lanes and columns but still could not get what is happening in the indexing part.